# Trying to produce different random numbers every time a loop is executed

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, random, simulation

```
SRate = [5,5,5]
Bots = 120
NQueue = 3
TSim = 100
Exp = 2
DDistance = 1
Lambda = 40 # 120/3 = 40
import random

Elist=[]
AvgSRate = 5
def Initilization(AvgSRate,Lambda,Exp):
    return float((Lambda/(AvgSRate**Exp))*(1+(1/10)*(2*(np.random.seed(-28)) - 1)))

for a in range(1,361):
    Elist.append(Initilization)
```

I am trying to produce a set of randomly generated numbers between 0 and 1, so decimals for the initialization of a simulation, however It spits out the same values every time the loop is executed, so when I print Elist I get a list of all the same values. Also the list has `<Function Initialization at "the number">`, could someone help me eliminate that portion from the printed list to only have the numbers.

Comment: "It spits out the same values every time the loop is executed". How can you tell? You're not printing anything and it looks like the list will only contain function references, not numbers. If you're going to say, "I'm printing the numbers in some code I didn't share here", then please share that code too.

Comment: You need to call `Initialization()` by adding parenthesis and putting the parameters in.

Comment: Im returning the float value from the defined function and appending it to the Elist, and I know it is, because I had print on to test and saw the output

Comment: In your code, `Elist` is a list of the function object of `Initilization`. Printing it, you get those function objects. This code never calls the function. Also: Why are you *seeding* the random number generator with a constant value (`-28`)? Shouldn't you just be seeding the RNG once and  call `np.random.rand()` which gives you numbers in `[0;1]`? At least here, `seed()` definitely returns `None`. Is this really the actual code or are you transliterating from memory?

Comment: No i'm converting the code from MatLab to Python, and learning Python

Comment: @LoganLaite If that's your code you are not calling that function. You just adding a reference to the function to a list. I'm guessing your output looks something like this `[<function Initilization at 0x0000000003439D90>,...]`

Comment: Yes, thanks, I fixed that. Just learning guys lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `np.random.seed(-28)` is just seeding the random generator [[Documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html)] , it does not return any random numbers , for getting a random number use - `np.random.rand()` .

Example -

```
return float((Lambda/(AvgSRate**Exp))*(1+(1/10)*(2*(np.random.rand()) - 1)))
```

If you want to seed the random generator, you can call it before calling the `for` loop that calls the `Initilization` function.

The function after this should look like -

```
def Initilization(AvgSRate,Lambda,Exp):
    return float((Lambda/(AvgSRate**Exp))*(1+(1/10)*(2*(np.random.rand()) - 1)))
```

Also, one more issue, is that you are not adding the value returned from the function call to the list - `Elist.append(Initilization)` , you are just adding the function reference.

you need to change that to `Elist.append(Initilization(<values for the parameter>))` to call the function and append the returned value into `EList` .

Comment: I wanted to use the same seed as matlab which was -28, but thanks.

Comment: You can use the seed, its fine, but not inside the expression, you need to get the random number inside the expression right?

Comment: His problem is he is not calling his function. Just adding a reference to the list.

Comment: Numpy's rnd doesn't take negative values. Also, don't seed the RNG inside the function. If you do this, you restart the RNG at the same value, i.e. when you do `numpy.random.seed(8); p = numpy.random.rand()`, `p` will always be the same number.

Comment: @IanAuld Yes, sorry didn't even notice that issue, updated the answer.

Comment: @dhke ok yea, just tested it, updated the answer to set it only before calling the `for` loop, so that it is only set once. Thank you.